# Should I put ntlk.download() in my .py file?

Tags: python, nltk, spyder

For some reason, when I put `nltk.download()` in my `.py` file after `import nltk`, it doesn't run correctly in Spyder. It does run with the anaconda prompt though. Should I include it in my `.py` file? If so, how do I get Spyder to be ok with that?

Thanks!

Comment: "doesn't run correctly" - please explain.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like spyder blocks connecting to the external `qt` library that must be launched to create the interactive downloader window. I wouldn't bother looking for a solution, because:

> **Don't call `nltk_download` from your program** unless you're writing an installer. **Ordinary nltk code should rely on the data being already downloaded.**

Perhaps you've heard that github briefly blocked the entire nltk download service due to too many download requests by (too many?) rogue scripts. Don't abuse the service, or your IP address might be the one blacklisted next time.

If you are really writing a program that will be distributed and needs to obtain its own data resource, either include the resource in the distributed bundle or make the download conditional on failing to load it. E.g.,

```
try:
    tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
except LookupError:
    nltk.download("averaged_perceptron_tagger")
```

Use the download ID (the first column in the interactive downloader) for whatever resource your code needs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want actually. If you just need the corpus in nltk, you don't have to put nltk.download() in you code but run nltk.download() once in the shell and download the corpus you need. Remind there is another function called nltk.download-gui(). You can try it in spyder or maybe you should change the graphics backend to Qt5 in your spyder settings if that's the problem.